# How can I publish the powerapps, which will be implemented in other tenant site like Standalone?

Tags: powerapp

I have created edit item powerapps on the list. Now I want to export this app to the another tenant site. 
Now, how can I publish this powerapps?

Answer (score 1):

please check the **Exporting  and Importing an app** Sections in the [Environment and tenant app migration through Packaging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/environment-and-tenant-migration)

The steps are as follow

**Export:**

1. In http://web.powerapps.com, click or tap Apps, select the ellipses for the app you want to migrate, and then select Export (preview).
2. When the export package page opens, enter a Name and Description for the package.
3. Within the ‘Review Package Content’ section you can optionally add comments or notes or change the setting for how each individual resource will be imported into the target environment during package import.
4. When you are done select Export and the package file will begin downloading within a few seconds.